# Constitutional amendments of India

Tags: constitution, india, amendment

Despite Article 4 stating that a constitutional amendment is not necessary for Articles 2 and 3, why was the 7th constitutional amendment passed for state reorganization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Articles 2 and 3 allow for Parliament to admit new States to the Union of India and alter the boundaries of States already in the Union.

Article 4 requires that such laws amend two of the *schedules* to the Constitution that list States.  The Schedules are documents that are attached to the Constitution.  They spell out details that would clutter up the text of the Constitution.  Normally amendments to any of the Schedules would require the amendment to the Constitution process, but as the intention of Articles 2 and 3 is to allow for enlargement of the Union without requiring a Constitutional amendment, Article 4 permits modification to specific Schedules by law.

Article 4 does not prevent a constitutional amendment from also altering the Schedules too.  While law is the simplest way for the boundaries of the States to be altered, a Constitutional amendment is another alternative.  In general, anything that can be accomplished by law can also be accomplished by constitutional amendment, as the constitution is a higher form of law.

The seventh amendment does more than modify boundaries.  It alters articles 153, 171, 258 (among others) (to clarify the role of Governor, make changes to the size of the State Legislative council, and modify the relationship between Governors and Union territories) And Schedule 7 (To vary the powers of the Federal and State government) These changes could not have been made by law, and required a Constitutional amendment.

So a constitutional amendment was passed, because changes were made to the constitution that went beyond those permitted by Article 4.